# ASP.NET with SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am starting a new project in ASP.net MVC. I am fairly new to it, I also plan to have SQL Server Express as my database. However I don't really know how to connect both of them. I know how to add a connection, but when it comes to Identity ( the ASP.net Authentication system ). I am clueless in how to proceed and create it.

1. Should I work with SQL Server, or just make it local in EF.
2. If using SQL Server should I replicated the Identity database in
   SQL.
3. Are there any tutorial/book for MVC 4/5 on how to create a web application that fully utilize SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I work with SQL Server, or just make it local in EF.

You should use SQL server, as it will be saved on your end too as well as it would be available to the user's end too! It is best way (at least for me). You would be better going if you use SQL Server for your application.

You will have some data backed up on your server. And user will be able to get the data too. You can check out other features of Sql Server on msdn too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

> If using SQL Server should I replicated the Identity database in SQL.

All you need to save here, is the user's data and the data that he would provide you with such as his location and other data is needed!

Sql is the basic server for your databases.

> Are there any tutorial/book for MVC 4/5 on how to create a web application that fully utilize SQL Server

Yes! http://www.asp.net/mvc

This is the official website for ASP.NET MVC! You will learn basics to the professional skills related to MVC, you can also try to Google it out, I mean some of the tricks might be missing there, you can find those tutorials on the Google and some other sites!

Comment: I like your answer, a bit confuse on the second questions, I create a table USER with the info I want, but when I create a controller how would I grant access to user who are 10 or older?

Comment: Ummm I am not perfect in MVC, but you can go to the link I provided and learn MVC there! :) It would be easy for you too..